# jsp (java server page ) on apache2

Tags: jsp, apache2

Is it existing some module for jsp(java server page) like (mod_python, mod_asp, mod_perl,...) for apache2 on windows. Without installing another web server.

Answer (score 1):

You need at least need a JSP/Servlet container on top of Apache HTTPD, for example [Apache Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org). Apache HTTPD can be connected to Apache Tomcat using [mod_jk](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/).

Apache Tomcat in turn can also be used as a webserver, but that's not its primary purpose. With the mod_jk you can just serve the JSP/Servlet resources from Apache Tomcat through Apache HTTPD.